# Determining address memory of a library

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, gcc, xcode4

I'd like to know if somebody would know some tools which can tell you the address memory for a static or dynamic library written in C++ (for windows, linux and macos).

Thanks

Comment: Are you wishing to know how much memory is used, or where the library resides in memory? Modern OS have taken to randomizing library locations to make it harder for malware to exploit them.

Comment: Actually I think I gave a bad explanation. I compiled boost for x86 and x64 architecture the I compiled the librairies for cpp-netlib, when I run my code I have some runtime error so I would like to check if the library are compiled against the right architecture. I'm a bit over my head here so feel free to set me straight. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [readelf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf) for Linux, which displays information about ELF files. You can use it to know the addresses of shared libraries (implicitly loaded dynamic libraries) as well as addresses of all the static symbols. You can't however use it for libraries which are explicitly loaded at runtime. You can turn off the Address space randomization in Linux as well.

Comment: Thanks I'll check that. Please read my comment above to be sure that we are on the same page.

Comment: I didn't find a tool for the rest thanks.